# Chrome extension inject content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Добрый день. Прежде не сталкивался с Chrome Extensions, но нужно на скорую руку накидать скелет расширения с функционалом примерным Greasemonkey (на том же firefox)

В просматриваемые сайты нужно внедрять javascript код, который бы исполнялся не в песочнице, с правами пользователя. Перелопатил много форумов и топиков, но везде одни костыли. Как greasemonkey и ему подобные приложения внедряют код в страничку?

И еще замахнусь на совсем волшебный функционал, который просто меня бы спас:
На уровне самого расширения есть "системные" функции, например  [`GM_xmlhttpRequest`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest). Эта функция будет доступна в нашем исполняемом JS-файле, а реализована в расширении. В какую сторону смотреть, чтобы примерно понять алгоритм реализации такого функционала?

Дело в том, что у меня уже есть много функций написанных под Greasemonkey и нужно чтобы они заработали в рамках своего расширения для Хрома.

Задаем еще один вопрос, который просто был бы для меня подарком.
В Дополнениях Хрома есть такая вещь как [chrome.app.window](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window). Было бы идеально открывать новый сайт в новом окне *(я знаю, что оно откроется в другом процессе и с другой сессией)* , внедрять туда скрипт с дополнительно реализованными функциями (см выше). При этом чтобы все это максимально напоминало обычную работу с браузером. Дело в том, что в chrome.app.window можно записать только iframe или webview, а эти компоненты несколько ограничивают комфортную работу (нет адресной строки браузера и тд).

Все это нужно для того, чтобы один сайт можно было открыть несколько раз (под разными аккаунтами), а в рамках одного браузерного окна это сделать проблематично (из-за общей сессии).

Буду очень благодарен за **любую** помощь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С `greasemonkey` не работал, но с хромом знаком.
Установите порт этого расширения на `Chromium`-совместимые браузеры: [`Tampermonkey`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=ru).
Скрипты обещают полную совместимость, т. е. публичный API один.

---

Если в разрешениях (`permissions`) [запросить доступ](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns), тогда CORS не помеха, используйте стандартный `XMLHttpRequest`.